# cannot locate phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I successfully installed phpmyadmin, via `apt-get install phpmyadmin`

However I can't find the directory for phpmyadmin, I want it to appear on `/var/www/phpmyadmin` so that I can use it via URL.

Where is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your phpmyadmin files in /usr/share/phpmyadmin directory.

If you really want the files in /var/www/phpmyadmin use the following command:

```
cd /var/www && sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin phpmyadmin
```

Comment: In that case, I recommend accepting the answer.  This will give the poster credit, and mark this problem as solved.